# Why does Chrome store its cache in my home folder?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

It seems like Chrome stores its cache in my home folder. Every site that I visit cause Chrome to store files in my home folder. It is pretty annoying since my home folder is always filled with tons of folders.

Is it a normal behavior? If not, how can I fix that?

Few notes:

- The home folder is populated only when Chrome is active.
- I tried to reinstall Chrome (Deleted from Applications folder, and reinstalled), it didn't help.
- I tried to delete all the Chrome user profile data—it didn't help.
- Below is a partial list of the content I currently have in my home folder (these are all folders):

  `cm.g.doubleclick.net`
  `www.w3schools.com`
  `d1clufhfw8sswh.cloudfront.net`
  `d33j9ks96yd6fm.cloudfront.net`
  `a.walla.co.il`
  `server.exposebox.com`

Comment: It's not the cache, which is stored in `~/Library/Caches`

Comment: I'm gonna say that is NOT normal behavior, because I use chrome all the time, and I don't have anything in my home folder that shouldn't be there

Answer (score 0):

```
> Is it a normal behavior , if not , how can I fix that?
```

Take a [look](https://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory):

> Cache Directory
>
> The cache directory follows the XDG specs:
>
> ```
> Google Chrome: $XDG_CACHE_HOME/google-chrome, which defaults to ~/.cache/google-chrome
> Chromium: $XDG_CACHE_HOME/chromium, which defaults to ~/.cache/chromium
> ```
>
> **If you pass --user-data-dir=/path/to/foo, the cache will be under
>   /path/to/foo.**

Answer (score 0):

The configs are in your /home by *default* and the cache can be bypassed/redirected as mentioned above or via *chrome://cache*